# Errors when trying to copy some data from a 2-D array to another

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to write a simple program that reads and writes in xlsx files.

I have managed to import data from the file, and turn it into a dictionary.

But this array is arranged in a way that bothers me:

the array is something like this:

```
{
'position': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6},
'lastname': {0: 'Hamilton', 1: 'Bottas', 2: 'Verstappen', 3: 'Leclerc', 4: 'Vettel', 5: 'Albon'}, 
'firstname': {0: 'Lewis', 1: 'Valtteri', 2: 'Max', 3: 'Charles', 4: 'Sebastian', 5: 'Alexander'}, 
'team': {0: 'Mercedes', 1: 'Mercedes', 2: 'RedBull', 3: 'Ferrari', 4: 'Ferrari', 5: 'RedBull'}
}
```

(using F1 drivers as an example, don't pay attention)

I would like to transform this array into something that looks more like this:

```
{
0: {'position': 1, 'lastname': 'Hamilton', 'firstname': 'Lewis', 'team': 'Mercedes'},
1: {'position': 2, 'lastname': 'Bottas', 'firstname': 'Valtteri', 'team': 'Mercedes'},
2: {'position': 3, 'lastname': 'Verstappen', 'firstname': 'Max', 'team': 'RedBull'},
...
}
```

So that I could use the following code

```
for data in array:
    print(array[data])
```

to print **ALL the data on Lewis Hamilton**,

then **ALL the data on Valtteri Bottas**, etc

and not

**positions of ALL drivers**

**names of ALL drivers**

So, basically my array is like this
`data[rowname][driver]`
and I want it this way
`data[driver][rowname]`

My code below, trying to transfer data from an array named data
to an array named drivers

```
import pandas

import_file_path = "test.xlsx"
data = pandas.read_excel(import_file_path)

data = pandas.DataFrame(data)
data = data.to_dict()

newdriver = {}
drivers = {}
lines = 0

# getting number of lines in the array
for a in data:
    for line in data[a]:
        lines += 1
    break

# for as many drivers as present in the array
for i in range(lines):
    for column in data:
        newdriver[column] = data[column][i]
        # store the driver's data in a temporary variable, field by field
    drivers[i] = newdriver
    # storing driver data in a row of our final array

    print(drivers)
```

The final print statement results in this:

```
{0: {'position': 6, 'lastname': 'Albon', 'firstname': 'Alexander', 'team': 'RedBull'},
 1: {'position': 6, 'lastname': 'Albon', 'firstname': 'Alexander', 'team': 'RedBull'},
 2: {'position': 6, 'lastname': 'Albon', 'firstname': 'Alexander', 'team': 'RedBull'},
 3: {'position': 6, 'lastname': 'Albon', 'firstname': 'Alexander', 'team': 'RedBull'},
 4: {'position': 6, 'lastname': 'Albon', 'firstname': 'Alexander', 'team': 'RedBull'},
 5: {'position': 6, 'lastname': 'Albon', 'firstname': 'Alexander', 'team': 'RedBull'}}
```

The same driver in every line of the array.

I've investigated the issue, and it would seem that this line:

```
newdriver[column] = data[column][i]
```

also updates the data in the `drivers` array.

Halfway through the process of storing data into `newdriver`, "Lewis Bottas" appears in the `drivers` table, when I'm not even editing it.
Which makes no sense to me. (Lewis Bottas isn't a real driver)

```
{0: {'position': 2, 'lastname': 'Bottas', 'firstname': 'Lewis', 'team': 'Mercedes'}}
```

I suspect that the `drivers[i] = newdriver` makes `drivers` and `newdriver` share the same memory address, and thus, updates their values at the same time.
It's like I've created a pointer without wanting to. I just want to copy the values, not make them share the same address.

Any sort of help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to import anything 
Tested on: 
Python 2.7 , 3.7.5

```
def convert(array):
    newArray = {}
    for index in range(0,len(v['position'])):
        newArray[index] = {
        'position': array['position'][index],
        'lastname': array['lastname'][index],
        'firstname': array['firstname'][index],
        'team': array['team'][index]};
    return newArray
```

Edit: To do this Dynamically

```
# Input must be { StringOrNumber: { Number: SomeValue }, etc }
def convertDynamically(array):
    newArray = {}
    mainKeys = list(v.keys())
    for index in range(0,len(v[mainKeys[0]])):
        tmp = {}

        for key in mainKeys:
            tmp[key] = array[key][index]
        newArray[index] = tmp

    return newArray
```

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer my question though. I would like to create the new table dynamically, without hard-coding the field names in my function. This will do for now though, so thank you for the help.